Eating One's Ancestors: The Extent of the Belief in Gilgul in the Form of Flora and Fauna
Given that reincarnation in the form of animals or plants has a precedent in Jewish thought see here citing from the Sefer Hagilgulim. In addtion, in the Sefer Shemiras Halashon, there are quite a few references to being reincarted as other animals due to the sin of Lashon Hara (sorry forgot the Chapter Numbers). Furthermore, I remember a story being told of the Arizal wishing "good shabbos" to apples growing on trees.
That being said, is there any discussion of eating animals or plants that may be a gilgul of of a person? Would there be an issue of Kibbud Av V'aem by eating one's parents if this were to be pointed out be a kabbalist?
Or perhaps, on the contrary, would it be a tikkun for their soul? There is a story from the Berdithever that when holding up a chicken with a "treif" rendering injury sadly told it that it had not completed its Tikkun, which necessitated being consumed by a Jew on Shabbos.
What got me thinking about this is what I heard on a philosophy podcast citing Pythagoras who didn't eat meat for this very reason.

The food that you eat is not the soul that is dressed within any given creature or plant. In fact, in regard to animals, the emphasis is to remove the blood in order to make it fit for consumption because the animating soul is carried within the blood. The body that remains is an empty husk. That is what you consume. Regarding a human soul being incarnated within another species, this is highly unusual.

You probably confuse Judaism with Eastern philosophies. IIRC, in Judaism, no one suggested that once dead a person can reincarnate fully into another person, animal, or plant, rather it was proposed that different "unfulfilled" parts of it get recycled. So even for those who support reincarnation, it is never a wholesome person's soul dwelling in a chicken or an apple, so you don't get to eat your parents.

Well from the sources that I've seen it is apparent that the plant/food is in full possession of mental faculties. Additionally, reincarnation is a form of suffering to atone for sins making it probable that the entity that sinned should bear the consequences of its actions. See also the Q&A in the back of this past week's "Toras Avigdor" where he attributes the possibility of a soul reincarnated as a dog attempting to enter his shul to rectify its ways and being rebuffed by Rabbi Miller with logic that only a human soul can understand.
